# stop mediaplayer playlist after one loop

Tags: mediaelement.js

I am using media element player for my website for playing my tracks as a playlist. But if I don't give loop:true the playlist is not working. it gets stop after each track. Also if I give loop:true playlist keeps repeat. I don't want that too, Please suggest a solution

Comment: Welcome to SO, You are advised to attach code snippet of what you have tried, for better understanding.

Comment: Here is my code which I use for mediaelement for audio <script>
  $(function(){
   $('audio').mediaelementplayer({
    loop: true,
    audioHeight: 30,    
    audioWidth: '100%',
    playlist: true,
    playlistposition: 'bottom',
    features: ['playlistfeature', 'prevtrack', 'playpause', 'nexttrack', 'loop', 'shuffle', 'playlist', 'current', 'progress', 'duration', 'volume'],
    keyActions: []
    });
   });
  
   
 </script>

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found support of playlists in medialement js. Maybe you are using [this](https://github.com/duozersk/mep-feature-playlist) plugin?
If so, it looks like it is plugin's bug, and it should play next song in playlist without loop option. For me, helped to changing plugins function `playtrack` in such a way: 
instead of `t.play();` writing that code:

```
t.$media.on('canplay', playIt);
function playIt() {
    t.play();
    t.$media.off('canplay', playIt);
}
```

I will create a pull request, and if its realy bug, but not a feature, and thay accepted pull request, it will work fine in next versions of plugin.